# Can you convert a string with brackets and array formatting into an array?

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv

I am processing a CSV file, and in one of the columns are cells that have the a string in an array format. Here is what accessing those cells looks like:

```
$csv = Import-Csv $filelocation
foreach ($line in $csv)
{
   Write-Host $line.ColumnName
}
```

Output:

```
[Property=[value1,value2,value3]]
[Property=[value1,value2]]
...
```

You can see that each cell outputs a string with an array structure. I want to treat each individual string as an array with `Property[0] = value1`, etc.

Is there a simple way to do this? Otherwise, I assume I will need to use Reg Ex.

Comment: The sample output you've provided seems to imply that the property values are strings. If so then if the string contains commas then it's going to be difficult with Regex. Can you provide the actual contents of the CSV file?

Comment: I cannot share the whole file, I think it has sensitive data, but here is a partial snippet from it using a raw text editor: `,,,,,"[AsymmetricKey=[]]","[AppAddress=[[AddressType=Reply,Address=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob]]]","[AppAuxiliaryId=[]]",,,,` Here you can see a bunch of empty columns and a few of these "array like" strings.

Comment: What happens if a value of a property contains a comma?

Comment: I would hope to be able to navigate like a array of dictionaries. Something like: `foreach($value in $line.ColumnName.AppAddress) { write-host $value.AddressType }` would return "Reply" for that line.

Comment: What happens if a value of a property contains a comma? i.e. `[Property=[value1,"value2a,value2b",value3]]`. And then, if it contains `"`? `[Property=[value1,"value2a,value2b","value""3"""]]`?

Comment: I don't think I have thought that far ahead. I assumed that this string was in a standard 'array/ditionary' format, and I hoped that there was some function like `$string.ToArray()` which would handle this, but it does not seem that is the case. In that case, I will parse it in my own way.

Comment: What is a "standard 'array/dictionary'"? That's why I'm asking.

Comment: You should be able to use a combination of regular expression and `-split` operator for parsing the data into an array. It's not quite clear, though, whether you want the values as an array, or the whole string as a hashtable.

Answer (score 2):

Oh! Sorry...dont see the file content: ,,,,,"[AsymmetricKey=[]]","[AppAddress=[[AddressType=Reply,A‌​ddress=urn:ietf:wg:o‌​auth:2.0:oob]]]","[A‌​ppAuxiliaryId=[]]",,‌​,, 
Ok...if all file content like this we can do somethisng like:

$patch = get-content 'D:\test\testing!.csv'

```
$pl = $patch.Length - 1

for ($i=0 ; $i -le $pl ; $i++) {

$patch[$i].Replace(",,,,,","").Replace(",,‌​,,","").Replace("Reply,A‌​ddress","Reply.A‌​ddress").Split(",")[0]
$patch[$i].Replace(",,,,,","").Replace(",,‌​,,","").Replace("Reply,A‌​ddress","Reply.A‌​ddress").Split(",")[1]
$patch[$i].Replace(",,,,,","").Replace(",,‌​,,","").Replace("Reply,A‌​ddress","Reply.A‌​ddress").Split(",")[2]
$patch[$i].Replace(",,,,,","").Replace(",,‌​,,","").Replace("Reply,A‌​ddress","Reply.A‌​ddress").Split(",")[3]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to search some info, think its can be work (but not sure):
>
> $patch = get-content 'D:\test\testing!.csv'
>       $pl = $patch.Length - 1
>
> ```
> for ($i=0 ; $i -le $pl ; $i++) {
>
> $regex = "urn:ietf:wg:o‌​auth:2.0:o2b"
>
> $val = $patch[$i].Replace(",,,,,","").Replace(",,‌​,,","").Replace("Reply,A‌​ddress","Reply.A‌​ddress").Split(",")[1]
>   if ($val.Contains($regex)) 
>   {
>  $val
>  }
> }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

You try to do something like this:

```
$csv = Import-Csv Path:\testing!.csv -Header V1

foreach ($line in $csv) {
    $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        First = $line
    } #| select First #
    @{Name='First';Expression={($_.First).Split(";")[1]}}
    $obj1 = $obj | select -ExpandProperty First
    $obj1.V1
}
```

Comment: How does this parse `"[Property=[value1,value2,value3]]"` into an array?